# htaccess RewriteRule isn't working as expected

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm making a blog like website in PHP. So I have to rewrite my URLs. 
I have two urls like:

> /post.php?name=something&slug=somethingElse

And

> /tutorial.php?name=something

So I want to rewrite it like

> /post/something/somethingElse

And for the second one

> /tutorial/something

So I'm using following lines in .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)[/]?([.+]?)$ $1.php?name=$2&slug=$3
```

But it isn't working as I expect to.. Tried Google and Stack answers but that didn't help.

Comment: What did you expect and what is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it this way in your website root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ $1.php?name=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ $1.php?name=$2&slug=$3 [L,QSA]
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)